# Eclipse : how can we know the implementation classes for an interface in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE

I have a interface in my workspace called as Service .

Please tell me , how can i know the implementation classes for this interface ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Open Type Hierarchy" or press <kbd>F4</kbd> when your cursor is on the interface.